# How to properly add strings to QListWidgets?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

In the following code the method `exec(const char *cmd)` runs a bash script and returns the output as a vector of strings. The intent is to create a `QListWidgetItem` out of each of those strings and add them to a `QListWidget` on a little GUI that I have created, but the `QListWidgetItem`s are not created successfully. I always seem to be required to use a `const char*` to create either a `QString` or `QListWidgetItem`, it will not allow me to create one using a string variable.

You can see what I am going for in the line: `QString nextLine = txtVcr.back();`
There is an exception thrown here, it wants `QString` set to a `const char*`, for example  `QString nextLine = "Hello, World!";`

**How do I go about getting the strings from my vector and creating `QListWidgetItems` out of them to add to my `QListWidget`?**

In C# everything was rather direct in that I could add strings or whatever else to any container/widget.  Is there an intermediate step that I am overlooking with these "QWidgets"?  Perhaps I should be casting to "Q" types?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    vector<string> exec(const char *cmd);
    vector<string> txtVcr = exec("/home/rhurac/getServices.sh");

    while (!txtVcr.empty())
    {
        QString nextLine = txtVcr.back();
        ui->uxListWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(nextLine, ui->uxListWidget));
        txtVcr.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your problem is how to convert std::string to QString. Am I right?

Comment: @CodeDreamer Is that the proper way to do this? Or is there another method entirely that would be preferable? At this point I'll take anything!

Comment: @drescherjm It is just a little method that calls a one-line bash  $systemctl --type service | cut -d " " -f 1 | grep .service  It is the first part of a simple little GUI (similar to "Services" tab in msconfig). Everything works great with the regular strings of the vector. Just looking for the right way to make a QWidgetListItem out of those strings.

Comment: Try : `QString nextLine = QString::fromStdString(txtVcr.back());`

Comment: @CodeDreamer and @drescherjm are right. Try `ui->uxListWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(txtVcr.back().c_str(), ui->uxListWidget));`

Comment: Alrighty thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't use QListWidgets and other QxyzWidget classes. They are depricated, and left in Qt for compatibility with old code (Qt3 basically).

Use QListView and QStringListModel for your use-case. E.g.

```
QListView *lv = new QListView();
QStringListModel m;
QStringList data = QStringList()<<"AAA"<<"BBB"<<"CCC";
m.setStringList(data);
lv->setModel(&m);
lv->show();
```

P.S.: Sorry, it doesn't answer your question directly. But unless you have to support legacy code, don't touch QListWidgets!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? Why wouldn't the documentation mention this? https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html

Answer (score 3):

To get a `QStringList` from a `std::vector<std::string>`, you'll need to use `QString::fromStdString` on all the elements.  For example:

```
#include <QStringList>

#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

QStringList convert(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    QStringList l;
    l.reserve(v.size());
    std::transform(begin(v), end(v), std::back_inserter(l),
                   &QString::fromStdString);
    return l;
}
```

Then you can populate a `QStringListModel` feeding a `QListView`, as suggested in other answer.

Comment: I'm very impressed by your pictures ;-)