# How to show std::vector in QT properly?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qt-creator, qvector

I have small class "Dictionary", where I contain all data in std::vector. I want to show this data in QT application. So I did a small research and I found that I should use ListView like this:

```
ui->WordList->setModel(new QStringListModel(QList<QString>::fromVector
                                            (dict->getQVector())));
```

But this looks like really show. I have to update model of ListView each time I add new element to vector. And also I have to add function to my Dictionary class to get QVector:

```
QVector<QString> getQVector() {
  QVector<QString> qv;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
      qv.push_back(QString::fromStdString((std::string)container[i]));
  }
  return qv;
  }
```

...and this looks also really slow.
So I have a question: should I rewrite my Dictionary class using QTL? If so, how to display QVector using ListView (or maybe something else) in convenient way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084336/how-to-properly-add-strings-to-qlistwidgets

Comment: You could write a custom QAbstractListModel subclass that directly returns the data of the std::vector

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all of your requirements for your Dictionary class, my suggestion would be to replace the internal std::vector with a QStringListModel, and then set that as your model for your view. When you make a change to the QStringListModel, it will be reflected in your view automatically.

Alternately, make your Dictionary class a model by subclassing it from QAbstractItemModel. You could still keep your std::vector as the internal data structure and then your "data" and "setData" methods would read from and write to the std::vector.

Without knowing more about what your Dictionary is for, whether it's sorted or not, whether it contains duplicate entries or not, and so on, it's hard to make solid recommendations on an appropriate data structure.